# pass vba variable to sql

Tags: sql, vba

I have implement a command in access that once its clicked, it will insert new row to the corresponding table. The problem is its not passing variables to SQL, it just insert rows with ACTUAL string..like myDate...myId....Can some one help me to fix that...

```
Private Sub Command34_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command34_Click

    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim myQty As Long
    Dim myAdj As Long
    Dim myReason As String
    Dim myId As Long


    Dim sqlMyDate As String
    Dim sqlMyQty As String
    Dim sqlMyAdj As String
    Dim sqlMyReason As String
    Dim sqlMyID As String


    Dim mySqlInsert As String

    sqlMyDate = "SELECT TOP 1 [DATE OF PHYSICAL INVENTORY] FROM [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] WHERE [JOB #]=""2188"" ORDER BY [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS].[ID] DESC;"
    sqlMyQty = "SELECT TOP 1 [REQ'D ADJUSTMENT] FROM [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] WHERE [JOB #]=""2188"" ORDER BY [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS].[ID] DESC;"
    sqlMyAdj = "SELECT TOP 1 [REQ'D ADJUSTMENT] FROM [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] WHERE [JOB #]=""2188"" ORDER BY [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS].[ID] DESC;"
    sqlMyReason = "SELECT TOP 1 [REASON ADJUSTMENT REQ'D] FROM [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] WHERE [JOB #]=""2188"" ORDER BY [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS].[ID] DESC;"
    sqlMyID = "SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] ORDER BY [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS].[ID] DESC;"

     myDate = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMyDate).Fields(0).Value
     myQty = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMyQty).Fields(0).Value
     myAdj = 0 - CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMyAdj).Fields(0).Value
     myId = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMyID).Fields(0).Value + 1


     If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMyReason).Fields(0).Value = Null Then
     myReason = "No Reason"
     Else
     myReason = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMyReason).Fields(0).Value
     End If

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] ([ID],[JOB #],[DATE OF PHYSICAL INVENTORY],[QTY FORMED],[QTY WIP],[QTY ON HAND],[REQ'D ADJUSTMENT],[REASON ADJUSTMENT REQ'D],[DATE POSTED]) VALUES (""&myId&"",""2180"",""&myDate&"",""0"",""0"",""&myQty&"",""&myAdj&"",""&myReason&"");"

Exit_Command34_Click:
    Exit Sub
Err_Command34_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command34_Click
```

Comment: have you checked what the SQL actually is, try doing a MsgBox with the sql statement to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL _
"INSERT INTO [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] " & _
"([ID],[JOB #],[DATE OF PHYSICAL INVENTORY],[QTY FORMED],[QTY WIP],[QTY ON HAND], " & _
"[REQ'D ADJUSTMENT],[REASON ADJUSTMENT REQ'D],[DATE POSTED]) " & _
"Select " & _
"(" & myId & ",2180," & myDate & ",0,0," & myQty & "," & myAdj & "," & myReason &")"
```

There's a few problems here - to do string concatenation in VBA, it should work like this

```
dim myString as string
dim myValue as integer
dim myStringValue as string

myValue = 5
myStringValue = "Five"

myString = "Concat an integer, like, for instance , " & myValue & " like that, and a string, for instance : '" & myStringValue & "', like that.
```

So if the values you're inserting are integers, just end the string, put in an &, put in the value, put in another &, and then put in the double quotes.  If you're inputing a string, put a single quote, then a double quote to end the string, then an &, then the variable, then another &, then a double quote to open the string, then a single quote to finish the quotes around the variable.  So in a SQL statement:

```
sql = "Insert into mytable (mycolumn) select '" & myStringValue & "'"
```

edit : just read your variable types, this statement should work - -

```
DoCmd.RunSQL _
"INSERT INTO [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] " & _
"([ID],[JOB #],[DATE OF PHYSICAL INVENTORY],[QTY FORMED],[QTY WIP],[QTY ON HAND], " & _
"[REQ'D ADJUSTMENT],[REASON ADJUSTMENT REQ'D],[DATE POSTED]) " & _
"Select " & _
"(" & myId & ",2180,#" & myDate & "#,0,0," & myQty & "," & myAdj & ",'" & myReason &"')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know vba very well but i am guessing something like

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [PHYSICAL INVENTORY FINISHED GOODS] ([ID],[JOB #],[DATE OF PHYSICAL INVENTORY],[QTY FORMED],[QTY WIP],[QTY ON HAND],[REQ'D ADJUSTMENT],[REASON ADJUSTMENT REQ'D],[DATE POSTED]) VALUES ("+ myId+ ","+ 2180 + "," + myDate +"," +0+"," +0+","+myQty+ "," + myAdj  +"," + myReason +");"